# Best way to break up large class into smaller ones in PHP

Tags: php, class

I'm mostly an OOP newbie, and am fiddling around in CodeIgniter building a very basic ORM (maybe for future usage - now mostly for learning).

At this point I have a large class called ORM which my models extend. So a widgets model will have methods like get() (which basically gets all the rows in the 'widgets' table), and get_with_related(), etc.

I'd like to split up this class into a few smaller ones. Maybe if I have a base ORM class, and a 'reader' class (which has get(), etc.), a 'writer' class (which would have update(), save(), etc.), and maybe a utilities class.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Should I just include and instantiate the reader and writer classes in the constructor of the base ORM class and use it like this?

```
$widgets = new Widgets();
$all_widgets = $widgets->reader->get();

$widgets->writer->update('description', 'here is a new description', 357);
```

Is there a term I can google to find out the ways of organizing classes like this?

Comment: This ain't a BBCode forum, indent your code by four spaces (or use the 101010 button) to mark code as code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Codeigniter specifically but I don't think it's necessary to break it off into separate read/write classes.  In fact, in this instance that might actually be *bad* practice because in OOP a model is supposed to represent a single entity.  You should google DAL (Database Abstraction Layer). If have a Widgets model then it's perfectly ok to have both getters and setters.  My point is that it may not be the *best* practice in your case just to simply break off into smaller classes.  This should always be purpose-driven.